# TextBox ActiveX component displays oddly in Powerpoint during presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, activex

I'm trying to use a TextBox ActiveX component in a Powerpoint presentation. The motivation is to collect notes from the audience on the slide without having to exit presenter mode.

I have been able to add the component to the slide and it looks fine whilst making the presentation:

[image: Screenshot of a slide with a big yellow text box component in the centre.]

However, when I press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, it seems to duplicate the text box with the topmost instance offset from the intended location:

[image: Screenshot of the same slide in presenter mode, with the text box offset and containing some text.]

As shown, the functionality I want to achieve works fine. It's just the appearance/positioning of the TextBox which is wrong.

Is there any way to correct this? Or some workaround to get the TextBox to render the same at write-time and run-time?

Comment: You could fix the X and Y co-ordinates on the control, so it's always in the same place (0,0 is top left)

Comment: @spikey_richie This works when I set it to exactly [0,0], but when set to anything else the duplication/offset behaviour occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old, but I had the same problem and google brought me here so maybe this will help someone.

If you have an external monitor hooked up it'll double the box and mess up the alignment. I don't have a solution that keeps the second monitor, but at least it's a starting point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).